# A good resource to learn about the intuition and optimization models behind Markovitz modern portfolio theorem

Tags: optimization, risk

I would like to learn about the Markovitz theory because I am going to interview at a financial firm that uses variants of it extensively.

I am looking for a resource to learn about the intuition and optimization models behind Markovitz modern portfolio theorem. Any pointer to a book or webpage would greatly help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of options:

- [Michaud (2008)](http://books.google.de/books?id=dzWjKNYGjDUC&dq=michaud%20resampled%20efficiency&hl=de&sa=X&ei=16O_T4CGE4zAtAbvq5TLCg&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAA): Personally, I really like that book. It starts with an intuitive explanation of Markowitz theory and shows empirical shortcomings as well. It then gives a simple workaround (basically, a Monte Carlo simulation to reduce the impact of errors in input parameter estimation, to which the optimization is quite sensible to).
- [Elton et al. (2009)](http://books.google.de/books?id=aOtcTEQ3DAUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=elton%20gruber%20modern%20portfolio%20theory&hl=de&sa=X&ei=xaS_T4CoPIextAa5wviSCg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=elton%20gruber%20modern%20portfolio%20theory&f=false): This book probably never will be the most fun you ever read, but it is a very thorough introduction to modern portfolio theory.
- [Markowitz on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVGpfzMrlX4&t=2m45s): And why not listen to him himself ;-) I really like that interview, although it probably won't be enough for your interview.

Hope that gets you started.

Answer (score 1):

I find the books of Kritzman very intuitive - yet mathematically accurate:

- [Kritzman (2000)](http://books.google.de/books?id=iqMdG4TTWNYC&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false): Very gentle introduction
- [Kritzman (2003)](http://books.google.de/books?id=GPjp_ZRsyEoC&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false): Goes a little deeper but still very understandable